# System Restart menu with no keyboard

Tags: windows-xp, reboot

How do I get round this? I fired up my other PC this morning, having hibernated it. The 'Restoring state' screen appeared, the progress bar at the bottom ran across the screen, and then nothing. I switched off the PC, then  back on, and it booted to the System Restart menu (the one that offers to delete the hibernated data and boot from scratch or try to restart again. Here's the kicker - I use a Microsoft wireless keyboard, the drivers for which aren't loaded until Windows has started. So I can't do anything with the menu - I can't change the selection with the arrow keys or accept the selection with Enter.

I've tried plugging in a spare USB keyboard and rebooting but it doesn't seem to get recognised and I've no response from the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use USB keyboard for this menu. Just make sure that legacy USB compatibility is turned on in BIOS. That will allow it to work even during boot.

Answer (score 0):

Try repairing the wireless keyboard.

If the Wireless keyboard was USB and the new keyboard you are using is also USB, it could identify a different error in your computer - can you try using a different USB socket for the time being to test.

If you have a PS/2 Keyboard, try using that for the moment just incase it a USB setting in the BIOS that is not enabled.

Usually they are able to be detected before windows has started and the drivers are simply for additional components such as hot keys.